# is this usage of 'likely to' correct?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to write a document in which the author describes the scenario in which
he asks a question to the audience, and he says the obvious answer could be one of the below sentences.

Which one seems correct?

> 1. Most of the users would likely to say "Yes".
> 2. Most of the users would likely say a “Yes.”

Comment: er 2. seems more correct. To correct 1, you should say 'Most of the users would be likely to say "Yes".'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple grammatical errors in your OP including in the two example sentences. Before mentioning those I would add the following additional possibilities to @ian's list above:

> Most of the users would be likely to say 'Yes'.
>
> Most of the users would be likely to answer with a 'yes'.
>
> Most of the users would be likely to give 'yes' as an answer.

Now as regards other matters, I have rewritten your opening sentence with corrections in capitals. Why are you using both 'use' and 'write'? I have eliminated 'use' assuming it should not be there.

'I am trying to write a document in which THE author describeS a scenario in which he askS A question to AN audience, IN WHICH the obvious answer WOULD BE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING:

a) MOST OF THE USERS WOULD BE LIKELY TO SAY 'YES'. b) MOST OF THE USERS WOULD BE LIKELY TO ANSWER WITH A 'YES'.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on
    whether *likely* functions as a **predicate adjective** in the clause,
    **or**
    whether *likely* functions as an **adverb** in the clause.
    Both are possible, but they have different syntas.

- *Most of the users **would be likely to** `X`*  (pred adjective)

If it's a predicate adjective, it requires an auxiliary ***be*** (all predicate adjectives do)
**and** it can take an infinitive complement clause, with *to*.

- *Most of the users **would likely say** `X`*   (adverb)

If it's an adverb, it doesn't take any auxiliary, it goes before the main predicate,
**and** it takes no complement clause at all (since it's not a predicate), so no *to*.

That's all, really.

Answer (score 0):

neither is exactly correct, here are some suggestions:

1. Most of the users would likely say "Yes".
2. Most of the users would likely respond (or reply) "Yes".
3. Most of the users were likely to say "Yes".